# Type of Request.host object in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi, webapp2

I'm currently finishing a little personnal kind of universal URI Parser for my GAE Application.

Globally, everything is fine and run pretty smoothly, but now that I review my code, I'm wondering if the self.request.host object that I use to parse information is an array or a string.

I now that it could seems obvious for some, but I've search for docs about it on Google's site , python's site and Django's as well without finding any relevant informations about the type of the object (Or I badly search maybe).

So if someone, could tell me if there is somewhere a documentation which contain the type of the object (as for the php docs for exemples ;-) ) I would be really happy ;-)

I now that I could use isinstance to retrieve it, but I would prefere a doc from python himself because I'll have to do the same thing with many other objects that I aim to use.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's a "table"?

In any event, a webapp2 request object inherits from [webob.Request](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#id1), which is well-documented. The `host` attribute is a normal string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake when I typed my question, I would ask about array and not table.
Those two words are the same in my native language, that why ;-)

Ok, Noticed that, I'll go study this part of the documentation.